How nested <if> works in Spring Boot Logstash?
regarding to the official documentation https://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#nested_if_element
This example is no longer supported, as it has a  element nested within 
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <!-- <if> nested within <root> disallowed -->
    <if condition='isDefined("A_VARIABLE")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="SOME_APPENDER" />
      </then>
    </if>
</root>

and can written as
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>        
<!-- <if> surronding <root> is fine -->
<if condition='isDefined("A_VARIABLE")'>
    <then>
        <root>    
            <appender-ref ref="SOME_APPENDER" />
      </root>    
    </then>
</if>

It doesn't specify if having more than one  tag it is needed put the level and if it could provoke any conflicts, I assumed if the level match there is no problem.
Or else we need to specify the root level only once.
Anyone was working with this new format and can clarify this please? Thanks in advance
